# print the next word after a match

Tags: text-processing, cut

I am trying the following in a bash script on Linux:

```
envA="prdk8s--staging-a"
envB="prd-k8s--sandbox"

for envCode in $envA $envB;
do
   Code=$(echo $envCode | cut -d "--" -f 1)
   echo $Code
done
```

However, this fails:

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try 'cut --help' for more information.
```

---

Expected output:

```
staging
sandbox
```

Is there a way to print the next word after "--" in the variable values $envA and $envB?

Comment: could you also please comment about the downvote so that it helps me in future? thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shell's own parameter expansions to trim the leading and trailing components:

```
for envCode in "$envA" "$envB"; do 
  t=${envCode#*--}
  printf '%s\n' "${t%-*}"
done
staging
sandbox
```

You can use `##`, `%%` if you want to remove the *longest* rather than the *shortest* leading and trailing matches - it's not clear from your examples which is required.

See for example [BashGuide: Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)